# How can I upload files in ASP.NET5 using ajax?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, file-upload, asp.net-core, ng-file-upload

I've read many posts about uploading files using a traditional html form and using IFormFile on the server side (ASP.NET5 RC).  However, I would like to upload a file using ajax (specifically ng-file-upload) and IFormFile doesn't seem to work when using ajax.  The request payload looks like:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryqGdWTqE8FFBpVPbA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[0]"; filename="mydoc.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf


------WebKitFormBoundaryqGdWTqE8FFBpVPbA--
```

I believe the files are being passed up in the Request.Body, but I'm not sure how to extract them from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this using the Kendo UI upload control, I also found that an IFormFile parameter was not populated. I got it working using Request.Form.Files

```
 foreach (var file in Request.Form.Files)
        {
                var fileBytes = new byte[file.Length];

                await file.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(fileBytes, 0, (int)file.Length);

                SaveDoc(fileBytes, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), docTypeId, enrollmentId, Path.GetExtension(fileName).Replace(".", ""), comments: comments);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is populated when You upload each file one by one:

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
{
    ...
}
```